# MySQL database migration UTF-8 issues with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

I'm migrating my existent database into another server. To achieve that I've exported and imported the database using phpMyAdmin SQL queries. Everything works fine, except that some UTF-8 characters appear broken in the website. I fetch them using the same PHP code (on a different server but with same PHP extensions and version).

Example of a string as I see it on the new website and on the databases (both old and new) (using phpMyAdmin): `pÃ©ri-prothÃ©tique`

Example of a string as I see it in the old website `péri-prothétique`

As you can see, PHP used to automatically encode the characters the right way even thought the characters are mangled in the database, but doesn't do so anymore (not even if i explicitly `utf8_encode` or `utf8_decode` the result). I even tried forcing `$mysqli->set_charset("UTF8")` on every connection to no avail.

Both the web server, the database server,server connection, PHP and the tables use UTF-8 or utf8mb4 charset and collation, and are setup the same way as the old ones.

The only difference I see is that the new database server is MariaDB instead of MySQL and its webserver is nginx instead of Apache.

New database specs picture from phpMyAdmin:

[image]

Old database specs picture:

[image]

New webserver specs on which the website and PHP runs (same specs as old one but different server):
Apache 2.4    PHP 7.0

How can I get back that old correct encoding? Why doesn't PHP automatically decode them right anymore?

**UPDATE:**
Using `mb_detect_encoding` I see that PHP in both new and old version detects ASCII or UTF-8 on the query results, depending on whether there's at least an UTF-8 symbol or not.
The issue is that on the new version PHP doesn't display the UTF-8 symbols right even thought it detects the string encoding as UTF-8.

**UPDATE 2:**
thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) I figured out why my entries were mangled: **double encoding** arose from the fact that the database collation was `latin1_swedish_ci` while the tables collation was `utf8_general_ci`.
This doesn't answer the question thought since the old website was automatically "translating" those mangled characters, rendering them right in the HTML, and I want to replicate that behavior into the new website which is a different one but with the same code and php.ini settings.

Comment: Don't use `utf8_encode`/`utf8_decode` that is for ISO encoded data. Aside from that change the code is the exact same? If you query the two DBs is the data the same before the PHP interaction?

Comment: Yes, queries with phpMyAdmin return the same data. I tried decode/encode just to see if something would happen, without real expectations

Comment: MariaDB 10.0.32 is a little older than 5.6.39, but they should be "the same" with respect to this Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for double encoding, use `SELECT HEX(col)...`  `é` should come back `C3A9` (proper utf8), but instead shows `C383C2A9` (double encoding).

See: [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

If you have actually determined that you have double encoding, then the fix involves

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(col USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4);
```

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

Yes, "double encoding" is a silent bug -- two wrongs make a right (sort of).

Comment: Thanks, I already saw your linked answer and it helped me a great deal in knowing what caused this problem. However I'm reclutant using the fix you proposed since it transforms properly encoded utf8 chars into `?` and I can't be sure i don't have any in my database short of manually controlling every record (which is of course unfeasible). Isn't there any other way which targets only `latin1` encoded chars leaving the utf8 ones alone?

Comment: If separate _rows_ have separate issues, you will have to write a program to deduce the state of each row and apply different actions to different rows.  I might be able to help provide expressions such as `CONVERT(...)` for individual cases.  If you can identify which _rows_ need fixing via SQL, then do `UPDATE ... =CONVERT(...) WHERE ...`

Comment: Also, carefully check the "Best Practice" in my first link.  (It sounds like your many attempts at rebuilding are missing one of the items.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should check for your MariaDB configuration.

First check your php code in order to know if there isn't misleading typo ( but i think it doesn't)

Second, check for your MariaDB database/tables structure [[extracted from here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/setting-character-sets-and-collations/) ]:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
```

Third, check for your MariaDB files config (my.cnf)[[extracted from here](https://coderwall.com/p/pns4pa/setting-up-unicode-defaults-for-mariadb-or-mysql) ] :

```
    [client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
```

Then restart your server :

```
mysql.server restart
```

Hope it will help you to fix your problem bro.

Bye

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I modified the MariaDB files config (from utf8 to utf8mb4) but i can't restart the mariadb server from ssh (doesn't recognize "service" command). I'll try to restart the machine and hope it'll work

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work :( I'm already sure 1st and 2nd points are not the issue (well, regarding the second point, tables use utf8 and not utf8mb4 but so do the old ones)

Comment: Well.. That's too bad ! 
I'm sur you should search trought your config file or something like this.. 
What about SQL Insert data with special encoding character ? Does it work properly ?

Comment: after changing database collation to utf8 (which apparently conflicted with the tables collation, shouldn't the collation be cascading?, creating those mangled characters by double encoding) the inserts mantain utf8 compatible records in the database. The point is that the old database had those nasty chars but PHP automatically "translated" them in utf8 compatible one, and my question still remains: why doesn't it do so anymore?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and you need _client, _connection, and _results .

Comment: @Kitra - `utf8` and `utf8mb4` are identical for western European characters.  So, the change did not help.

Comment: @Kitra - The database settings are just _defaults_ for newly created tables.  The discrepancy is unimportant.

Comment: @RickJames  Regarding the `utf8mb4` change: I suspected that, but I literally tried everything else I could think of.
Regarding database settings: I thought so too, but since changing it solved the double encoding problems on `INSERT` it turns out that the queries encoded in `latin1` the data due to database collation, only to reencode it to `utf8` due to table collation. Or at least this is the only plausible reason I can think of.

Comment: Did you solve your issues ? 
Drop your DB then try to edit your my.cnf file with those line : 

**[client]**
**default-character-set=utf8**

**[mysqld]**
**character-set-server=utf8**
**collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci**

**[mysql]**
**default-character-set=utf8**

Then check your tables/database collation using SQL request.
As @RickJames said you should try to convert your tables collation : Convert to binary format then convert to UTF8 format if your collation aren't updated by previous step.

Comment: @Snics sadly changing charsets and collation didn't solve my issue. Regarding the conversion fix, I'm afraid to use that since it destroys properly encoded utf8 chars and I'm not sure I don't have any in my db.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the changes on existing data? It will not work. You need to add the data again to see the changes. Remove all the data from the new database and add again.

Comment: What are you refering to? I didn't make any changes to the data, just copy/pasted via SQL queries from the old database

Comment: Delete all the data from the new server database and restore it from your old server database backup.

Comment: Of course I already did that multiple times, the problem still persists.

Comment: Can't you restore from the terminal? Seems PHPMyAdmin is not using the UTF-8 connection.

Comment: I don't think PHPMyAdmin is to blame. If you carefully read my question (I've reworded it to make it a little more clear) the data into the two databases is the same (both with mangled double-encoded chars). The problem seems that the `SELECT` results are not automatically decoded right anymore in either connection or PHP side.